# How to Call Powershell Copy-Script from VBS Logon Script

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I am currently in the process of converting a logon script from VBS to Powershell, and one of the subs, which updates a specific file if it is an older version, has been reduced to this:

```
sub UrgentSupportApp()
    On Error Resume Next

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "powershell -file ""\\DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs\UrgentSupportApp.ps1""", 0, true

    If Err <> 0 Then
        strMessage = "ERROR: Sub - UrgentSupportApp"
        DisplayCustomError(strMessage)
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I log in I am seeing this error:

> Number (dec) : -2147352567
>
> Number (hex) : &H80020009
>
> Description  : Unable to wait for process.
>
> Source       : WshShell.Run

I know the powershell works, as I have tested it as a standalone script. However, I am not sure if accessing it over the network has implications for the `env:USERPROFILE` variable (which user is in scope here?).

I tried changing the `bWaitOnReturn` parameter to `false`, and this resulted in no errors, but the script didn't actually do the work.

Does anyone have any tips as to how I can debug this or what might be going wrong?

The ps1 script looks like this:

```
$appsource = '\\file\Administration\Unused\Apps\IT Support App\IT Self Help.exe'
$apptarget = $env:USERPROFILE + '\desktop\IT Self Help.exe'

$oldapp1 = $env:USERPROFILE + '\desktop\Urgent IT Help Request.exe'
$oldapp2 = $env:USERPROFILE + '\desktop\IT Help Request.exe'

$currentversion = (Get-Command $appsource).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion

If (Test-Path $oldapp1) {Remove-Item $oldapp1}
If (Test-Path $oldapp2) {Remove-Item $oldapp2}

If (Test-Path $apptarget) {
    If (!((Get-Command $apptarget).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion -eq $currentversion)) {
        Copy-Item $appsource $env:USERPROFILE'\desktop' -Force
    }
}
Else {Copy-Item $appsource $env:USERPROFILE'\desktop' -Force}
```

It simply removes any of the files which have the old name, and then copies over the newest version if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6f11xft%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. Try msgboxing out the whole wscript.run line as caused here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/9bd8b093-598c-4d26-853b-8f9b2323746a/unable-to-wait-for-process-error-2002009?forum=ITCG. And this is from the generic error - `0x80020009 DISP_E_EXCEPTION Exception occurred`.

Comment: @Noodles Thanks for your comment - I ended up resolving this by using a different call to the Powershell script - will add an answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing the VBS call to:

`objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit \\DC1\NETLOGON\PSSubs\UrgentSupportApp.ps1"), 0`

I'm not sure why this works, but it does.

Please note that this is being called on a thin client via a log on script when the user logs on to computer.